# SSL Certificate Issue with bucket name containing dots ('.') while trying to use Virtual-Hosted url instead of Path Style for AWS S3 Bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-s3

I'm new to this AWS and I'm experiencing a very annoying bug with S3.

I created a bucket named with dots : my.super.bucket.

After uploading pictures to that bucket with name 'my-key', I get the URL.

It looks like this : https://my.super.bucket.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/my-key

Problem : The SSL certificate is not valid and every browser trying to display the picture does not because the certificate is only valid for one-level subdomains (*.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com).

Earlier it was working as I was using path-style request i.e. the URL looked like this
https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/my.super.bucket/my-key

But, as from september 2020, aws will no be supporting path-style base url on S3, I'm tring to change it to change it to Virtual-Hosted style.
I am using http**S**

One work around I know here is I can use '-' instead of dots. But is there any other way so that I can use virtual-hosted style with bucket name containing dots?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I see it, you may need to change the bucket name. Or you can make the content available through CloudFront with different domain name.

Comment: I used different domain name using CloudFront, it worked.